# Show the latest month and date in option based on dataframe

Tags: python, plotly

How the option can show / display the latest date according to the dataframe?

Example:
Today 03/02/2022 which is the latest date and month from the dataframe.

There have a month selection and a date selection which is based on the month selection.

Data:
[image]

Code:

```
 # create dropdown and display latest month based on df   
    dcc.Dropdown(id='month_dd', value= df['Month'].max(),
                  options = [{'label':x, 'value':x} 
                            for x in month_category],                     
                  ),

         dcc.Dropdown(id='date_dd', value=''
   
        ])

# create date dropdown according to month dropdown list
@app.callback(
    Output('date_dd','options'),
    Input('month_dd', 'value')
    )


def update_dd (month_dd):
    month_date= df.drop_duplicates(['Month','Settlement_Date'], inplace= False)
    relevant_date= month_date[month_date['Month']== month_dd]['Settlement_Date'].values.tolist()
    date_option= [dict(label=x,value=x)for x in relevant_date]   

    return date_option


#set last item as default value according to month dropdown list
@app.callback(
    Output('date_dd','value'),
    Input('date_dd', 'options')
    )


def default_value(latest_date):
    value = latest_date[0]['value']

    return value
```

Expected result:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the [0] to [-1]

```
#set last item as default value according to month dropdown list
@app.callback(
    Output('date_dd','value'),
    Input('date_dd', 'options')
    )


def default_value(latest_date):
    value = latest_date[-1]['value']

    return value
```